# Multiple iterations of sha2 on spark dataframe column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a use case where I need to calculate 5000 rounds of sha512 on the string column. So far I tried to use pyspark function sha2, python "old" UDF and python pandas udf for that. I'm looking for a way to speed up calculations.

**For pyspark** I was unable to define column that use sha2 5000 times (stack overflow even on displaying column definition) - I defined it using loop:

```
for _ in range(5000):
     column = sha2(column,512)
```

**For python** I defined similar function using hashlib:

```
def sha(text):
    for _ in range(5000):
        text = hashlib.sha512(text.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

    return text
```

But it introduces overhead of serialization/deserialistaion and data transmision.

I experimented with rewriting this function for **pandas_udf** but unfortunatly nodes on my cluster dont have pyarrow instaled and it will not change before I need to have working prototype.

So i'm looking for a way to speed things up.

- I dont know scala or java but I'm open to try using scala / java udf to speed things up - am I correct in assuming that switching to scala/java udf should produce speed up in this scenario?
- Is there a way I'm missing with pyspark to define such function?

Edit: I'm working with Spark 2.3 in python 3.7. So I don't have access to higher order functions introduced in 2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do it with SQL functions only. Having

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(["Hello World"], "string")
```

In **Spark 2.4** or later (earlier when using some proprietary platforms) you can

```
df.selectExpr("""aggregate(
    sequence(1, 5000),            -- Dummy sequence
    value,                        -- Init
    (acc, x) -> sha2(acc, 512)    -- Aggregation function
) AS hash""")
```

In **Spark 3.1** or later you can

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import aggregate, col, lit, sequence

df.select(aggregate(
    sequence(lit(1), lit(5000)),     # Dummy sequence
    col("value"),                    # Init
    lambda acc, _: sha2(acc, 512)    # Aggregation function
).alias("hash"))
```

**Edit** (if you cannot update):

In practice 5000 rounds of hashing are likely to more than offset cost of moving data around so you should be just fine with plain `udf`, especially for prototyping.

Comment: Unfortunetly I have spark 2.3 :(

Comment: re your edit - its a fair point that I didnt tought about, but I think I will still try to look for optimistaion for educational purpose - i.e. try to learn how to write simple scala or java udf and compare speed. If no one will give better answer in a day or two I will accept Yours. Thanks.